# What is the Opportunity Product?

Tags: standard-objects

I have question on opportunity and opportunity product.  I have a requirement where i need to store all the different services provided by us for each opportunity.  I am trying to accomplish this by creating a custom object.  Exploring sf, i see the opportunity product, but don;t know what it is used for.  Please throw some light.

Answer (score 13):

> Opportunity Product (API name OpportunityLineItem) is a Junction Object between Opportunity and Product2 .

An opportunity has to be linked to the Product for generating order or to do Quote management going ahead .The products linked to opportunity are known as opportunity line Item or opportunity product .The revenue is the sum of prices of these line items .

Have a look at sales data model from SFDC to explore more

[image]

Comment: So does it mean that i can save the different services provided by one opportunity here, why i am asking this is, i need to generate report on the services that are won or lost on each opportunity.  As it is a junction object, can i still add my custom fields to this.  Please help.

Comment: Yes you can add fields to it .You can create custom fields on opprtunity Products.

Comment: I set up look for opportunity Products and add a custom boolean field or picker and you can use out of box object.

Comment: i created few products, now i am trying to create the opportunity lineitem for an opportunity, how to create the lineitems for the opportunity?

Comment: i need to enter the services(opportunity line item) as few fields keeps changing every time, like from, to,number of prices. How to achieve this

Comment: To modify the Page Layout for Opportunity Products, go to Setup/Customize/Opportunities/Opportunity Products/Page Layouts. If you need to change the Multi-line Entry layout, you do this from within the Page Layout editor. Check out Help & Training for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItems) is a junction between Opportunity and Price Book Entry (PricebookEntry).  The Pricebook Entry is itself a junction between Product (Product2) and Pricebook (Pricebook2).

As for your requirement, it sounds like you're supposed to store every service you offer on an Opportunity even if it's not being sold on that Opportunity.  Is that correct?  If so, it doesn't sound like a requirement that has been fully thought through.  Why not only store the services being sold on that Oppty?

If that is the requirement and it somehow makes sense, then you could use Opportunity Products and create a trigger on Insert that gets all available Products and creates a OpportunityLineItem for each.

Comment: The requirement is to store the services offered by one opportunity, but the services are so different, like domestic and international.  for domestic services, the fields are different and for international services, the fields are different.  So where do u suggest to store these field values, in opportunity or opportunity product or product2.  I am new to sf, trying to use the existing functionality, instead of creating custom objects.  In the same way, i am trying to understand the existing features of sf, please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Would you sell domestic and international services on the same Opportunity?  If not, then you would create two Record Types on the Opportunity, one for Domestic and one for International.  The additional questions can be fields you create on the Opportunity instead of on the Product.

Comment: yes we sell domestic and international in the same opportunity also we need to facilate to sell other 8 services on the same opportunity

Comment: I would still recommend putting the fields on the Opportunity object.  Then in the layout, you could create sections for International and Domestic.  Since you can't recordType  OpportunityLineItems, it would certainly not be ideal, even if the fields were Service specific.  Any field you add to Opportunity products would be on every product.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about Opportunity Products as either

a) SKU(s) that you would quote and then, if ordered, receive a Purchase Order with line items for those SKU(s). You can also forecast by SKU this way

For example, if I were Dell, one of my Opportunities might have these Opportunity products

1. LAT-7440-16GB
2. MONITOR-27
3. SATA-1TB

or

b) Product Families that you sell one or more of on a given Opportunity (and where you want to do opportunity-product forecasting on)

For example, If I were General Electric, one of my Opportunities might have multiple Opportunity products:

1. Jet Engines
2. Support and maintenance
3. Professional services
4. TurboJet engines