# How can a flow access an opportunity's product?

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, opportunity-lineitem, product2

I need to access opportunity products through a flow, and I don't know how... I tried point at the product ID, but of course, it doesn't work. Can you help, please?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Opportunity Product?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45706/what-is-the-opportunity-product)

Comment: Thank you David, it might... I'm gonna investigate "you could use Opportunity Products and create a trigger on Insert that gets all available Products and creates a OpportunityLineItem for each."

Comment: OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntryId -> PriceBookEntry which is a junction between Pricebook and Product2. That is the schema you need to deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Cheng's suggestion, I was able to figure it out. I needed to understand what an Opportunity Product is.

First, I added a lookup field to my Opportunity Product, in order to match the person and the product. Might sound weird, but that's exactly how our activity works.

[image]

Then, I just worked a loop around those opportunity products.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand why the question is related to OpportunityLineItem if the object is customized.

One reason could be that the person running it doesn't have access to the Programme_de_Formation__c object.

To access the Product Id (Product2) the path would be Opportunity (Record) > OpportunityLineItem > Product2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Edgar: I was told to add OpportunityLineItem but the person wasn't able to help me solve it, still. So, sorry. From the flow, OpportunityLineItem is only a boolean HasOpportunityLineItem, so no direct way to access the product.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that Opportunity Products (also known as "Opportunity Line Items") aren't just a lookup: a single Opportunity can have a dozen (or more) different line items, all with different products.

Think of it like a grocery receipt: the Opportunity is the receipt itself, the Opportunity Products are the various lines *on* the receipt. One for apples, one for bread, one for chicken, and so on.

It does not make sense to be able to pick out "the" Product on the receipt. But what you *can* do is, similarly to that loop you've used in your screenshot, get all the  Opportunity Products whose Opportunity ID is the one listed in the Contract object, and then assign whatever information you need from them into the desired variable(s).